# Screen Dimensions in Visual Basic

Tags: vba, screen-size

How can you access the dimensions of the screen in Visual Basic? I have looked online and it says to use Screen.width and Screen.length, but it doesn't recognize those properties... any tips?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In VB you can use `Screen.Width` and `Screen.Height`. They're not in VBA but you can use an API call instead. Add these declarations:

```
Public Declare Function GetSystemMetrics Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal index As Long) As Long
Public Const SM_CXSCREEN = 0
Public Const SM_CYSCREEN = 1
```

Then use like so:

```
MsgBox GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) & "x" & GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN)
```

Comment: I'm sort of new to visual basic... so where should I put this code?

Comment: @Monkeyanator Put the first three lines at the top of the relevant file (outside of functions). Put the actual call(s) to GetSystemMetrics where you need the values.

Comment: Is there a way to center something on a form?

Comment: @Monkeyanator: Just to clarify, center something on a form or a form on the screen?

Comment: @Monkeyanator: I didn't think VBA's UserForms could be run-time resizeable could they? But okay, suppose you have a UserForm with a Button1 on it. Center it with this code on the form: Private Sub UserForm_Resize(): On Error Resume Next: Button1.Move (Me.InsideWidth - Button1.Width) / 2, (Me.InsideHeight - Button1.Height) / 2: End Sub: That should be four lines but you can't do separate lines in comments on this site.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4432/discussion-between-monkeyanator-and-boann)

Comment: It's better to create a new question instead of asking a second question in the comments to an answer