# auto adjust excel userform for different computer screens

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have an excel userform that opens fine and I can see full of it. But in some of my teammates computer it is not showing full, some of it is not visible. Is there a way I can make my userform show completely on everybody's screen irrespective of the screen and probably screen size? Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Yes. Use [Windows API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844171/screen-dimensions-in-visual-basic) to get the screen resolution of the screen in question and have code that sizes accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Untested but reliable websites:

[OzGrid](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/142634-vba-to-automatically-resize-user-form-depending-on-screen-resolution)

[Happy Codings](http://visualbasic.happycodings.com/forms/code48.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    With Application

        .WindowState = xlMaximized

        Zoom = Int(.Width / Me.Width * 80)

        Width = .Width

        Height = .Height

    End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's always better to add a few lines to explain your answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's always better to add a few lines to explain your answer.

Comment: Thank you very much everyone :) it has been a while writing VBA codes.